# Keep Alive Socket between Java client and VB Server

Tags: java, vb.net, sockets

I've created program to send and get data from client to server and for client i used java and server I used Visual Basic so how to set the connection between client and server is keep alive in a client(java) side?

this is the code from client :

```
public static void Client(){
    String print = "";
    String dataDB = "Hello server, From Client";
    try(Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", port)){

        clientSocket.getOutputStream().write(dataDB.getBytes("ASCII"));
        while (clientSocket.getInputStream().available() == 0) {
            Thread.sleep(100L);
        }
        byte[] data = new byte[clientSocket.getInputStream().available()];
        
        int bytes = clientSocket.getInputStream().read(data, 0, data.length);
        
        print = new String(data, 0, bytes, "ASCII");//.substring(4,bytes);
        
        while(print.length()>0){
            System.out.println("From Server : "+print);
        }
    }catch (IOException ex){
        System.out.println("I/O error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }catch(InterruptedException ie){
        System.out.println("error: " + ie.getMessage());
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The Java client is a console application, just sent and get data from server i tried to used `clientSocket.setKeepAlive(true);` but is not working.

Comment: Given that the internet is designed around failure (it was designed to work even if multiple nodes were removed by atomic bombs), you should *always* be prepared for sockets to close unexpectedly.

Comment: @JohnEason I fixed the tag

Comment: @NomadMaker is possible if i put the close connection in another method?

Comment: for example, i created properti private Socket clientSocket = null; and i make another method for handle connection and transaction, and another method for handle connection.close

Comment: Could you be closing the connection while it is still in use?

Comment: @NomadMaker i used timer for timeout, so when the program is timeout then i will call close method